# Smooth line with Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have one data set which contain data in two column about Gross salary and tax wedge.You can see data with code line below:

```
SAMPLE_WAGES_TAX_WEDGE_TEST<-data.frame(
  GROSS=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000),
  TAXWEDGE=c(30.1,30.4,30.7,30.9,29.1,28.9,28.6,28.5,27.9,27.2,27.1,27.0,27.0,26.8,25,24,23,21,19)
)
```

So my intention is to plot graph with plotly package and make some smooth line similar like function geom_smooth() from ggplot2.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

dat <-as.data.table(SAMPLE_WAGES_TAX_WEDGE_TEST)

fig <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~GROSS, y = ~TAXWEDGE, name = "Before reform", type = 'scatter',
               mode = 'lines',line = list(dash = "solid") )
```

I try with this line of code but I can't add smooth line so can anybody help how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how to solve this issue:

1) Convert `ggplot` object into `plotly`

```
ggfig <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=GROSS, y=TAXWEDGE) ) +
         geom_line() + geom_smooth()

ggplotly(ggfig)
```

2) `geom_smooth()` is based on the loess smoother. You need to fit the loess first and use it in `add_ribbons` in connection with `plot_ly` object. Check this great [blog entry](https://www.displayr.com/how-to-add-trend-lines-in-r-using-plotly/) (the last example) for implementation guidance on loess and other smoothers.

Answer (score 2):

Referring and complementing the answer in [Adding a smoothed line to a plotly chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037837/adding-a-smoothed-line-to-a-plotly-chart), you may directly use `plotly` with the `shape = 'spline'` option within the line marker specifications in order to get that type of smoothing (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation):

```
plot_ly(SAMPLE_WAGES_TAX_WEDGE_TEST, x = ~GROSS, y = ~TAXWEDGE, type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines', line = list(shape = 'spline', smoothing = 1.3))
```

where the optional parameter `smoothing` serves to (slightly) tune the degree of smoothing (see https://plotly.com/r/reference/scatter/#scatter-line-smoothing). Equivalently, using the specific `add_lines` trace function,

```
plot_ly(SAMPLE_WAGES_TAX_WEDGE_TEST, x = ~GROSS, y = ~TAXWEDGE) %>% 
  add_lines(line = list(shape = 'spline', smoothing = 1.3))
```